# Security for JSONP

Tags: jquery, asp.net, security, json, jsonp

How would I secure JSONP data, so only certain people can access the data?

Comment: Which DB are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the more common approaches is to generate an API key for each of those certain people, which basically acts as a username/password combination.  If you look at how popular APIs like Twitter work, you'll see that mechanism in action.

A large advantage that comes with using a authentication token that's separate from the user's regular authentication is that it can't be used to fully compromise their account.  So, if someone gains unauthorized access to the key, they can simply log in and request that their key be regenerated.

Comment: Hey Dave, big fan of your website Encosia. Question, do you think jsonp + generated token + referrer white list is a pretty secure way to go? I was looking into Stripe.com and they use a one-time authentication token for credit card transactions via client-side as well. I've built a prototype script library for my ecommerce system that allows pure JavaScript consumer using the above techniques cross domain with postMessage. Needs a one-time token for purchases and white-list for jsonp catalog data.

Comment: @kitgui.com: Keep in mind that the referrer header can be spoofed pretty easily, so don't bet too much on that particular mechanism as a security feature. With payment authentication tokens, I think the most important additional considerations would be to only return them via SSL and to he absolutely sure there are no CSRF or XSS vulnerabilities on the requesting site(s). High-value security isn't my primary expertise though, so I could be overlooking other important factors.

Answer (score 1):

On a web application, JSON data gets transmitted with the usual HTTP request stack. As such, you'd need a HTTPS connection to have assurance the data wasnt evesdropped. If you're after securing the server-side database, this is a different question.